# sbt-ghpages fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: git, github, sbt, github-pages

So I've done this exactly before without problem. I am on `master` branch of my project on GitHub. I created a new branch `git checkout --orphan gh-pages`, cleared it out, and pushed it to `origin`. I'm going back to `master`, inside directory `site` where my `build.sbt` is, and I run `sbt ghpages-push-site`. I see this error

> [error] fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

and then after building the API docs sbt exits with error from the above failed git. It goes without saying that `../.git` exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems this was a cache problem. Running `sudo rm -r ~/.sbt/ghpages/` and then trying again worked.